# setting default width to 960px for large desktops in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0

I am using joomla3 with the twitter bootstrap for the first time. I want my maximum widht to be 960 - so really I want to do away with the last responsive option.

I went to the customise page http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html and unchecked the "large desktops" option and downloaded etc

I put the two cs and js files in media/jui/css and media/jui/js but it didn't make any difference.

So I then tired this again, but altering the @gridColumnWidth1200 and @gridGutterWidth1200 to 60 and 20 (with and without the large desktops checked)

Nothing seems to make any difference so I guess I am doing something wrong

Can anyone please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why dont you set your max width in your template css?

protostar is already bootstrapped and has a max-width property in its template.css

Comment: I tried adding a media query so that above 959px the width was 960px - which of course worked fine but now all the columns are too  wide so they don't fit.1

Comment: check the protostar template for `.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
 width: 940px;
}` and the span properties after it ;)